# C# - Dynamic URLs depending on database rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, dynamic

I'm not sure how to explain it, but I'll make a try.

Let's say I do have a shopping-cart web, with many products listed, and I want to expand the info of each product when clicked.

The thing is, I want every product to have a unique url attached to it, so I can pass the link to my customers.

So if I add product "apple" to the database, I want that a new .aspx web gets created, and the textboxes filled with anApple.name, anApple.price, etc...

I want to have a unique url like www.mystore.com/products/apple, after I insert the product in the database.

I have NO IDEA how to start, so maybe you could send some words to start googling it?

Thanks!

Comment: Google "ASP.Net Routing" - typically your URL will be something like https://www.example.com/Products/12345 - 12345 will be the ID of the product in the database.  You will not have a separate .aspx for each product; you will have ONE view that loads its data dynamically depending on which ID is requested.

Comment: thank you very much